# How to access a directory under document root with new user

Tags: ssh, sftp, user-permissions

I created a new user clientespc under the new group sftpclientes. I want that user to have only access (read/write) to `var/pages/example.com/web/uploads`. However I can't do that. I guess that's because my `var/pages` directory is owned by the www-data user. But I already tried to put clientespc under the www-data group. But it also didn't work. I am only able to set the `useruploads/files` as clientespc's root dir.

My current configuration is:

root dir:

```
var/pages/example.com/web
```

sshd_config:

```
Match Group sftpclientes
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ChrootDirectory /useruploads
```

passwd for that user:

```
clientespc:x:1001:1004:,,,:/home/clientespc:/bin/false
```

But that's not what I want. What I want is to set the `var/pages/example.com/web/uploads` as the ChrootDirectory of the clientespc user, and grant it access only to that folder. How Can I do that?